# Having issues downloading a class file and importing into project

Tags: java, eclipse, class

I have an issue with my eclipse compiler. I was given a class file and I downloaded it to my bin file, however I am still getting issues when running the code. It says it doesn't exist.
[image]

Here is the structure. BinarySearchTreeBuilder is the only class file not working

[image]

Comment: _given a class file_ Is this for a school assignment specifically? This is not at all the way that external Java code is normally included.

Comment: You have to put that class in a separate folder, not into the `bin` folder, and then add this folder as class folder_ in _Project > Properties: Java Build Path_, tab _Libraries_, button _Add Class Folder_.

Comment: It is still not working and yes it is for a school assignment